# Grails:Replacing GORM with Hibernate class

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-domain-class

Consider a Grails domain Class:

```
class Rate {
    static belongsTo = [createdUser:User]       
    static hasMany=[cancelNo:CancelNo,property:Property ]
    Long id 
    String code 
    static constraints = { 
        id ( nullable:true )
        code( nullable: true )
    }   
}
```

Consider a java Class

```
class Rate {            
    Long id 
    String code      
}
```

I want to remove the domain class and need to reuse the java class

I have done all the mappings in `grails-app/conf/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml`

and created a groovy file `RateConstraints.groovy` inside that have given correct package of hibernate java-class and this

```
constraints = { 
    id ( nullable:true )
    code( nullable: true )
}
```

what i want to know is, Is it possible to write mapping inside this..? ie,

```
static belongsTo = [createdUser:User]       
static hasMany=[cancelNo:CancelNo,property:Property ]
```

if it is possible then how it can be achieved..?

Answer (score 0):

No if you are using Hibernate instead of GORM you have to use Hibernate's mapping syntax which is either XML or JPA annotations

Comment: is it possible to give trasients like this transients = ['startDate', 'endDate'] in RateConstraints.groovy